# World class doesn't display my background

Tags: background, libgdx, textures, render

I have a class called **World** that contains all the entities that make interaction with the player (obstacles, background, scenario) and this class has a method called **drawWorld()** in which draw all entities. The first thing I put on this method was the background, but it doesn't draw the background texture and I don't know why.

This render method is from my game screen and where I call the method **drawWorld()**:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // OpenGL clear screen
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(Gdx.gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gdx.gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the projection matrix for the SpriteBatch
    this.game.spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(this.game.orthoCamera.combined);

    // Act stage
    this.game.stage.act(delta);

    // SpriteBatch begins
    this.game.spriteBatch.begin();

    // Draw world
    this.world.drawWorld();

    // Draw stage
    this.game.stage.draw();

    // SpriteBatch ends
    this.game.spriteBatch.end();
}
```

And here I render the background:

```
public void drawWorld() {
    // Draw background
    this.game.spriteBatch.draw(this.background, 0, 0);
}
```

Without forget that I created the background texture:

```
// Load background image
this.background = Assets.manager.get(Assets.background);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A `game` object is referenced in the screen: `this.game.spriteBatch.begin()` and in the `world` object: `this.game.spriteBatch.draw(this.background, 0, 0)`. Is it the same `game` object?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed post, but yes, it is the same game object.

Comment: Did you remember to load `Assets.background` before calling `this.background = Assets.manager.get(Assets.background);`?

Comment: In the Game class I did Assets.load() and Assets.manager.finishLoading(). On my player class I did this.texture = Assets.manager.get(Assets.character), so it should work also in my World class. Do you want more code to see what's going on?

Comment: Yes. Specifically can you show how `this.game.stage` was initialized?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if this is relevant, because I just use the stage for my Player that is an Actor, but in the method create() in the Game class I did this.stage = new Stage(this.viewPort);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `Stage` with only a `ViewPort`, under the hood, the `Stage` [creates and uses it's own `Batch`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html#Stage-com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport-). So, in your `render` method, you have `game.spritBatch` drawing your background and then `Stage`'s `Batch` drawing the stage *within between the `begin` and `end` of `game.spriteBatch`*. That is a big no no.

The way this should be done is like this:

Creating the `Stage`:

```
this.game.stage = new Stage(this.viewPort, this.game.spriteBatch);  // For efficiency, you can use the same spriteBatch
```

`Render`:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // OpenGL clear screen
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(Gdx.gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gdx.gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the projection matrix for the SpriteBatch
    this.game.spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(this.game.orthoCamera.combined);

    // Act stage
    this.game.stage.act(delta);

    // SpriteBatch begins
    this.game.spriteBatch.begin();

    // Draw world
    this.world.drawWorld();

    // SpriteBatch ends
    this.game.spriteBatch.end();

    // Draw stage
    this.game.stage.draw();  // After spriteBatch.end()!! 
}
```

See the [docs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html#Stage-com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch-) for more about the `Stage(Viewport viewport, Batch batch)` constructor.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked. If I'll do a new game I always need to put the stage.draw() after the spriteBatch.end()?

Comment: Yup. If you look at `Stage`'s [source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.java), you'll see that `draw` calls `batch.begin` and `batch.end`. You can't do that between a different `batch.begin` and `batch.end`.